# Mod Rewrite Issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this and it works for that page.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
```

When I try to add another it doesn't work on the new page. What am I missing?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ product.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to do:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ category.php?param=category&param2=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?param=product&param2=$1 [NC,L]
```

But you can remove the first parameter `param` as you use another file for `category/`and `product/`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same regexp on the 2 lines, it will stop at the 1rst line. You can have for example :

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ product.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: I get a 404 when I try this.

Comment: it's an example, i don't know the path you really use for your website. What is the url that correspond to category or product page ?

Comment: https://www.rntus.com/category/airconditioning-heating/   then https://www.rntus.com/product/test-item-name/